# How can I take a break in Destiny 2?

Tags: destiny-2

Destiny 2 does not seem to let me pause the game at any stage of the single-player progress, be it in a campaign mission or otherwise.

I expect it to be strictly non-pausable during multiplayer matches like crucibles or raids etc., but when I press <kbd>Esc</kbd> in any single-player game everything would halt, letting the player take a break.

Apparently not in Destiny 2.
I can try hiding at some remote place but there is a chance that some monster eventually spawns nearby and kills me.

Do I need to be at a specific place to be able to pause the game properly, or Destiny 2 actually not a true single-player experience, so no pauses at all?

What alternative is there to take a small break (15 min.) in the game?

Comment: Several games disallow pausing in single-player, the Dark Souls franchise - for example - is very known for this. I've never tried Destiny, but is it difficult or possible to quit to menu?

Comment: @necklace You can quit to menu, but the game proceeds to run in the background.

Comment: Just go back to orbit, nothing there that can attack you. Also while doing quests and such you can usually continue from a certain checkpoint.

Comment: @Lyrion You could post that as an answer, if you believe it would solve the problem.

Comment: I agree with @Lyrion here Orbit as good a pause screen as there is

Comment: One question: Does the title have to include the game's name? It is already included  in the tags.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Destiny 2 does not have any method to pause the game during any activity. This is due in part to all activities having the potential to be multiplayer through teammates joining your fireteam, with the exception of a few solo activities.

For short pauses, you can simply allow your character to remain dead as there is no penalty for death in most single player activities.

Additionally, if you are inactive for too long (around 5 minute of no keyboard input), the game will kick you to orbit. Remaining AFK in the orbit screen will have the game send you back to the character select screen.

Comment: 'Kick someone into the orbit' would make one hell of a 'foot-in-your-ass' joke.

Comment: That timeout window changes depending on where you are, apparently. You can spend a lot more time at the tower, for ex, without being booted to orbit. Or open your inventory and you can stay there forever